# convert ISO date format to RFC 2822 format in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm getting date time as "2016-03-03T05:11:56" . i want to display this as RFC 2822 date format (Thu, 03 Mar 2016 05:11:56 GMT) . How to achieve this in XSLT 1.0?Any help is appreciated.Thank you all

Comment: Hi I tried one approach,but this year is leap year,so my logic is not working properly

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a common problem, so there are probably some libraries you can use for this. Once again, use google to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your datetimes do not contain time offsets or fractional seconds, you could use something like:

```
<xsl:template name="dateTime-to-RFC-2822">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>
    <!-- extract components -->
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($dateTime, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($dateTime, 6, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($dateTime, 9, 2)" />
    <!-- calculate day-of-week using Zeller's_congruence -->
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="$month &lt; 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="K" select="$y mod 100"/>
    <xsl:variable name="J" select="floor($y div 100)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="($day + floor(13*($m + 1) div 5) + $K + floor($K div 4) + floor($J div 4) + 5*$J + 6) mod 7"/>
    <!-- construct output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('SunMonTueWedThuFriSat', 3 * $h + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($dateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:text> GMT</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**: I believe the `GMT` suffix is obsolete, and you should use `+0000` instead.

Comment: If your dateTimes have fractional seconds, which RFC 2822 does not support, e.g. `2016-05-21T15:25:46.000Z`, you can strip them out by changing the last `value-of` to `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($dateTime, 'T'), '.')" />`.